# How to i remove my top margin in css?

Tags: html, css

I tried almost everything to get rid of the top margin I used the normalized.css reset, universal selector reset, HTML and body reset margin to 0.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>index</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron|Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
  <!--[if IE]>
            <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="content-area">
      <div class="text-logo">
        <h1>Peacon<span>TT</span></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #586f7c;
}
.content-area {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.text-logo {
  font-family: "orbitron", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to reset your `<h1>` margin.

Comment: Damn,thanks for answering so quickly and this is exactly the problem thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) property of your [`h1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) element to `0` to accomplish your goal:

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```